# Mongoose Schema with nest objects in arrays not working at creation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having difficulty creating an array of objects when creating a new document in Mongoose. The data I'm receiving looks something like this:

```
name: 'Greg'
payments: [{
  payment_value: 100,
  payment_value_formatted: '$100.00'
}]
```

And my schema, like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

const paymentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  payment_value: {
    type: Number,
  },
  payment_value_formatted: {
    type: String
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  date_formatted: {
    type: String,
    default: moment(new Date(Date.now())).format('MMM Do YY')
  }
})

const invoiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  payments: [ paymentSchema ],
},
{ 
  timestamps: { 
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  }
})

module.exports = mongooseConnection.model('Invoice', invoiceSchema)
```

And then in my controller:

```
let invoice = new Invoice(req.body);
    invoice = await invoice.save()
```

But this doesn't seem to be working for me. I keep getting this error:

```
"Value has unknown type. Value: {
  payment_value: 100,
  payment_value_formatted: '$100.00', 
  date: 2018-04-16T05:08:17.287Z,
  date_formatted: 'Apr 16th 18',
  _id: 5ad42fc13f9d3791c1dc681b 
}"
```

Comment: Show the actual code in the context to reproduce the error. At a glance, you would appear to be attempting to insert into a model with a "different" schema assigned to this one. So we'd like to see the model assignment for the actual model being used in the code as well, if that does not trigger something for you immediately and you still need help.

Comment: Also not certain, but it looks like you are "still learning" and might have taken the `timestamps` documentation too literally. Unless you specifically want those fields named with the names you have given, then simply `{ timestamps: true }` just adds the fields with the default names.

Comment: I am indeed still learning. Thanks for the tip about the `timestamps`. I've updated my code to include more context.

Comment: I think you best show us what `console.log(req.body)` shows us. It's likely there's some things in there you don't expect. You also really should not do things like `date_formatted` here. That's a "string" with a lot more bytes ( and pretty useless duplication ) than the 8-bytes required for the BSON date that is already there.

Comment: Do you want `req.body` as it arrives at the server? Copy/paste doesn't format things nicely, but it's basically:

`name: 'Greg'
payments: [{
  payment_value: 100,
  payment_value_formatted: '$100.00'
}]`

Comment: Copy/Paste formats things very nicely when you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49850089/edit) as opposed to posting in comments. Seeing it "exactly how it is" is the whole point, since the error suggests there is something there which you are not showing us.

Comment: Copy/pasting console.log output results in a jumbled mess, be it here or the post. In any case, I have actually solved it, and it's entirely a result of what you just said – there was some issue occurring elsewhere in my code that I didn't catch. I'm sorry to lead you down a rabbit hole, and it's my fault for *not* painting the full picture. Feel free to downvote the question. Thanks in any case for sticking with me here – I'm a noob.